# ¿Cómo le saco los milisegundos a una fecha de tipo LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, date

Utilizo la funcion `now()` de `LocalDateTime` para guardar la fecha actual y me la guarda con este formato:

> 2017-09-27 20:05:20.005005

El problema es que necesito la fecha sin los milisegundos, así:

> 2017-09-27 20:05:20

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje estás trabajando?

Comment: @Flxtr el lenguaje es java, ya lo edite en la pregunta. gracias

Comment: Una posibilidad es usar `withNano(0)`. Por ejemplo: `LocalDateTime fecha = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(fecha);
    System.out.println(fecha.withNano(0));` Ver la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#withNano-int-)

Comment: @AnaBelen esa edición debió haber ido en las etiquetas, no en el contenido de las preguntas, por esta ocasión lo he hecho pero para futuros casos tómalo en cuenta ;)

Comment: @Flxtr gracias! soy nueva en la pagina y de a poco voy aprendiendo como hacer las preguntas

Comment: y si utilizas un simpleFormatDate?, esto permite cambiarle el formato a la fecha dada.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalDateTime` tiene un método llamado [`withNano`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#withNano-int-), el cual puede servirte.

Pongo aquí lo que dice la documentación al respecto.

```
withNano

public LocalDateTime withNano(int nanoOfSecond)
```

> Devuelve una copia de  `LocalDateTime` con los nano segundos
>   alterados.

Esta instancia es inmutable y desafectada por la llamada de este método.

### Parámetros

`nanoOfSecond` - Los nano segundos a setear en el resultado, desde `0`  a `999,999,999`

### Retorna:

Un LocalDateTime basado en la presente fecha y hora (a la que le aplicas el método), con el nano segundo requerido, siempre que no sea nulo.

### Throws:

`DateTimeException` - Si el value nano es inválido.

---

Si a un objeto `LocalDateTime` le aplicas el método `withNano(0)` te devolverá la fecha sin nano segundos.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
LocalDateTime fecha = LocalDateTime.now(); 
System.out.println(fecha); 
System.out.println(fecha.withNano(0));
```

Resultado:

```
2017-10-10T00:04:30.631 //Fecha original
2017-10-10T00:04:30     //Fecha sin nano segundos
```

---

Si trabajas con fechas formateadas y en ningún caso te interesan los nano segundos, debes aplicar el método al objeto antes de aplicar el formato.

Ejemplo:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0); //Aquí le quitas los nanos
System.out.println("Antes : " + now);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formatDateTime = now.format(formatter);
System.out.println("Después : " + formatDateTime);
```

Resultado:

```
Antes : 2017-10-10T00:19:27
Después : 2017-10-10 00:19:27
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! voy a probar con esto. Saludos

Comment: No me funciono :( esa fecha la estoy guardando en una base de datos e igualmente sigo viendo los milisegundos

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes el código que dices no te funciona @AnaBelen? Si es para guardarlo en la BD no le veo mucho sentido, me parece que para guardarlo en la BD sin los milisegundos tendrás que limitar el tamaño de la columna... entonces no sería cuestión de Java, sino del manejador de base de datos que estés usando. De todos modos no le veo sentido, lo puedes guardar con los milisegundos en la BD y al sacar los datos se los quitas.

Comment: Claro el problema es que en una consulta HQL tengo que comparar si dos fechas son iguales, una  que esta guardada en la base de datos y otra que yo ingreso y con los milisegundos se hace imposible y siempre me devuleve que las fechas son distintas por mas que sean iguales.

Comment: Uyy ¿no te estarás ahogando en un vaso de agua?. Tienes tres escenarios posibles. **1.** Sacas el dato de la base de datos (con los milisegundos), se los quitas como explico en la respuesta y comparas ese dato con tu dato sin milisegundos.  **2.** Si es para guardar en la base de datos, guárdalo con sus milisegundos... es más preciso y luego no tendrás problemas al comparar dos datos que estén dentro de la base de datos. ¿Cuál es tu escenario? O bien **3.** Haz el `SELECT`  de la fecha que está dentro de la base de datos ignorando los milisegundos y compara.

Comment: 1. Justamente ese el el problema, la fecha se guardo con los milisegundos, entonces cuando hago la consulta la trae como esta en la base NO SE LO PUEDO QUITAR.3_ uso hibernate y HQL no puedo hacer el select ignorando los milisegundos o por lo menos no se como se hace

Comment: @AnaBelen si la fecha viene de la base de datos con los milisegundos entonces lo que tienes que hacer es quitárselos (al objeto donde almacenas esa fecha que viene de la BD) usando el método explicado en la respuesta. No habría motivo para que no funcione. Si no funciona por favor muestra el código editando tu pregunta y si da algún error ponlo también en la pregunta.